# How to update a Google email in Firebase using Google Sign in?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

Can someone help me with this task? I need to update the user Google account email, but I don't know how to do this properly. I would like to show the Google Sign in card, and then, the user select the new email, and if is different from the current one, I update it in Firebase.

Comment: Where do you need to update the user's Google account email? Also, what do you mean by "Google Sign in card"? Besides that, how do you know if the second user is the same as before, to only update the email?

Comment: I have an User Profile screen, where the user can change some informations. I would like to be able to update its Google Account. Using the "Google Sign in card" I refer to the white card that shows with all the users google email (this: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in), but I only can show it if I signout the current user. I'm trying to show it, compare the new email with the old one and update it if they are different

Comment: I see. In that case, what happens if your app is accessed by multiple users at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

When the user log's in, you would have access to that email address from the provider, you can simply compare the email provided against the user accounts email on firebase and update it directly.

Otherwise, you are looking at migrating accounts or linking them in some additional way.
Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking

This will allow you to manage the old and new email respectfully and update it within your Firebase user profile.